# "State.CONNECTED": CONNECTED cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, state

I want to check if my Android app is connected to the Internet. I copied the code I read in a book, here it is:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    int networkType = networkInfo.getType();
                    android.net.NetworkInfo.State networkState = networkInfo.getState();
                    if (networkState.compareTo(State.CONNECTED)==0)
                    {
                        //We are connected!!!
                    }
```

I've also given my app the permission to access network state, but Eclipse says this next to State.CONNECTED:

**CONNECTED** cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Even books are wrong, now? x(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you  have imported  the wrong state 
change

```
 if (networkState.compareTo(State.CONNECTED)==0)
```

to

```
 if (networkState.compareTo(android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)==0)
```